# Echo value of array

Tags: php, arrays

I searched, but the other threads don't answer my question, or I am just too stupid to see it.

```
$Questions = array(
1 => array(
    'Question' => 'Second question',
    'Answers' => array(
        'A' => 'First answer of Second question',
        'B' => 'Second answer Second question',
        'C' => 'Third answer Second question'
    ),
    'CorrectAnswer' => 'C'
)
);
```

How do I echo the value of 'CorrectAnswer'? Actually, I mean the value of 'C' (In this case, it would be "Third answer Second question"). $Value['CorrectAnswer'] gives me "C". But I can't just echo 'C', because in each array the correct answer is different. I am sure it's something really simple, but it escapes me. Sorry if I am not explaining it properly. This is the other piece of code:

```
foreach ($Questions as $QuestionNo => $Value)
{
    if ($Answers[$QuestionNo] != $Value['CorrectAnswer'])
{
        echo 'Your answer: <span style="color: red;">'.$Value['Answers'][$Answers[$QuestionNo]].'</span><br />
Correct answer: <span style="color: green;">'.$Value['CorrectAnswer'].'</span>';                        
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to name your variables with first letter capitalized. Usually class names get first letter capital. But still, that's your choice :)

Comment: @Whirlwind: yeah, should be camelCase, right?

Comment: Exactly...Or you can use underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the value for CorrectAnswer as lookup key against Answers:

```
echo $Questions[1]['Answers'][$Questions[1]['CorrectAnswer']];
```

Or in context of your code example, which is looping through `$Questions` array:

```
foreach ($Questions as $questionNo => $value) {
    $answerGiven = $answers[$questionNo];
    $correctAnswer = $value['Answers'][$value['CorrectAnswer']];
    if ($answerGiven !== $correctAnswer) {
        echo 'Your answer: <span style="color: red;">' . $answerGiven . '</span>';
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Correct answer: <span style="color: green;">' . $correctAnswer . '</span>';
    } 
}
```

Note that I have cleaned up the code to make it much more readable. You set the answer given and correct answer to variables and then use these for decision making and output.  I also indented code properly to make it more readable.

I would caution you against using initial caps for variable naming (or associative array key naming) in PHP as this is VERY non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$Value['CorrectAnswer']` would be `"C"`, so you can use it like so:

```
echo $Value['Answers'][$Value['CorrectAnswer']];
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it. So what it does is use the value of 'CorrectAnswer' as the position of the array 'Answers' which to echo?

Comment: @KardNails Yes, it would be as if you said: `$Value['Answers']['C'];`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like

```
echo 'Correct answer: <span style="color: green;">'.$Value['Answers'][$Value['CorrectAnswer']].'</span>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for this:

```
$Value['Answers'][$Value['CorrectAnswer']]
```

This should give you: 
  'Third answer Second question'

(well, only in the case where $Value references the 1st array in the $Questions array, that is.)

Comment: It should be `$Value`, not `$value`. Also didn't I already give this as an answer?

Comment: Well, that's the asynchronous internet for you!  We answered at the same time.  And you're correct, it should be $Value. I'll fix it.

Comment: Actually, about the async stuff. You're posted at about 6 minutes before me, so yes, it is repeat. However, I didn't see your post before I posted, due to refresh, I'm sure. Else I wouldn't have posted a repeat answer.

Comment: It's fine, I know you didn't copy me. I sometimes spend some time on an answer to just find out it was already posted.